# Is NPM install necessary

Tags: typescript

I'm working on an NPM library that uses socket.io and I'm using Typescript.

Lets say in my library I have a function similar to this:

```
public someFunction = (_socket: Socket) => {}
```

and in my app using this library is only calling this function, not socket.io directly, like this:

```
public anotherFunction = ():void => {
    myLibraryClass.someFunction(socket);
}
```

Clearly, my library needs to socket.io installed.

However, in cases where I am not actually calling anything in socket.io in my application, is it necessary to NPM install the socket.io library, or is it enough just to install the @types file?

Answer (score 0):

The `someFunction` method in your library receive the `socket` instance from the caller, and in your app, you invoke the `someFunction` method with a `socket` instance. So, in your library, `someFunction` do not actually create any instance of `socket` but receiving `socket` instance from the caller, it does not has to install socket.io package instead `@types` is enough. In your app, you invoke `someFunction` with a `socket` instance, so you have install socket.io package (and @types if your app develop with TypeScript too).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Based on what you are saying, it would seem that I don't actually have to import socket.io for either one. The socket object is actually created by Node's http module, never in any of my code. Does this does this sound correct?

Comment: Yes, if your code do not handle for creating socket instance then you do not have to install socket.io, install the `@types` is enough to tell TS language service the argument is type socket.